# List 2 fields of a content type and group them based on one of them with views

Tags: views, entities

I have on coupon content type with 2 fields. One is named "Campaign Owner" and the other one "Campaign Name". One owner might have several coupons generated by the site for a campaign. So the owner will have for example 20 coupons with the same campaign name. I want to create a list of campaign names and group them with campaign owner. So the list should be something like this:

### JACK(Owner Name)

1. Camp1
2. Camp2
3. Camp3

### JOE (Owner Name)

1. camp4
2. camp5
3. camp6

I've tried to create this with views but what I get is not what I'm looking for. Here is it:

### JACK

1. Camp1
2. Camp1
3. Camp1
4. Camp2
5. Camp2
6. Camp2

### JOE

1. Camp4
2. Camp4
3. Camp4
4. Camp5
5. Camp5
6. Camp5

As you can see. It lists all the similar campaign names. But kneed to get rid of the
similar items. 
How can I do such a thing?

Comment: Go to advance Query settings in view and check Distinct may gives correct result.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan No it doesn't work. They are not the same cause each row belongs to a published content with different NID. So they might be similar for us but they are not for the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "[views distinct](https://drupal.org/project/views_distinct)" module which checks the values of each row and then removes/aggregates the similar ones.